# Arduino error. Can;t find it

Tags: c++11, if-statement, struct, arduino

I am getting arduino error here.

```
struct student{
int num,ac,sp,co, sum = 0;
    if (ac>=30 && sp>=30 && co>=30) 
    ^
        sum = ac+sp+co;
};
```

I am just learning my way around C++ right now, so it can be a stupid mistake.. Thanks in advance.
exact error: line:12    col:6    [Error] expected unqualified-id before 'if'

Comment: [Find a good beginners book on C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), and start there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) 
[Here](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/47-structs/) you can read about what a struct in c++ is.
Briefly, it's a collection of other data types. All the logics (your if statement) should be placed inside functions.

2) 
Looks like you wanted to do something like this:

```
int num = 0, ac = 0, sp = 0, co = 0, sum = 0;
```

Instead, you initialized `sum` only. Other variables took default values.

---

I'm not sure I compeltely understand what you are trying to achieve, but try looking at this code (it's not Arduino, but you should get the idea):

```
struct Student {
    int num, ac, sp, co;

    int getSum() {
        if (ac >= 30 && sp >= 30 && co >= 30)
            return = ac + sp + co;
        else return 0;
    }
};

int main() {
    Student student;
    student.ac = 30;
    student.cp = 40;
    student.co = 50;

    cout << student.getSum();

    return 0;
}
```

Now, here is the problem.
Before calling `student.getSum()` you always have to initialize `ac`, `sp` and `co` (as I did in `main()`), otherwise you can get garbage results. To avoid this, give default values to each of your variables (constructor is a good place for this).

Comment: It's a part of bigger code. They have been initialized externally.